# Delete and copy message in gifted chat

Tags: react-native, dialogflow-es, react-native-gifted-chat

Using Dialogflow, I had onLongPress to GiftedChat component like this:

```
 <GiftedChat
   onLongPress={this.onLongPress}

   ....
   ....
/>
```

onLongPress returns context, message. Then you can show an ActionSheet and add the logic to delete and copy.

```
onLongPress(context, message) {
    console.log(context, message);
    const options = ['copy', 'Delete Message', 'Cancel'];
    const cancelButtonIndex = options.length - 1;
    context.actionSheet().showActionSheetWithOptions({
        options,
        cancelButtonIndex
    }, (buttonIndex) => {
        switch (buttonIndex) {
            case 0:
                Clipboard.setString(this.props.currentMessage.text); this code not work and brakes my app :(
                break;
            case 1:
               //code to delete
                break;
        }
    });
}
```

Here i have the send properties of code:

```
  sendBotResponse(text) {
let msg = {
  _id: this.state.messages.length + 1,
  text,
  //createdAt: new Date(Date.UTC(2019, 5, 11, 17, 20, 0)),
  createdAt: new Date(),
  user: BOT_USER,
};
this.setState(previousState => ({
  messages: GiftedChat.append(previousState.messages, [msg]),
 }));
}

handleGoogleResponse(result) {
  console.log(result);
  let text = result.queryResult.fulfillmentMessages[0].text.text[0];
  this.sendBotResponse(text);
}

onSend(messages = []) {
   this.setState(previousState => ({
    messages: GiftedChat.append(previousState.messages, messages),
 }));
 let message = messages[0].text;
 Dialogflow_V2.requestQuery(
    message,
    result => this.handleGoogleResponse(result),
    error => console.log(error)
  );
}
```

I did a very silly mistake this only works in arrow function unless you bind this manually to the normal function so have to use the arrow function in onLongPress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change `this.props.currentMessage.text`
to      `messages.text`
create the following function:

```
    onDelete(messageIdToDelete) {
    this.setState(previousState =>
      ({ messages: previousState.messages.filter(message => message.id !== messageIdToDelete) }))
    }

    onLongPress(context, message) {
    console.log(context, message);
    const options = ['copy','Delete Message', 'Cancel'];
    const cancelButtonIndex = options.length - 1;
    context.actionSheet().showActionSheetWithOptions({
        options,
        cancelButtonIndex
    }, (buttonIndex) => {
        switch (buttonIndex) {
            case 0:
                Clipboard.setString(message.text);
                break;
            case 1:
                this.onDelete(messageIdToDelete) //pass the function here
                break;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: hi, thank you for your help!! any idea how to do a logic to delete message?

Comment: do you want to delete message from the screen or from the backend server
I'm assuming you have a backend server setup to save the messages on some database

Comment: just the screen of the user

Comment: onDelete(messageIdToDelete) {
  this.setState(previousState =>
    ({ messages: previousState.messages.filter(message => message.id !== messageIdToDelete) }))
}

Comment: how can I declare here: case 1:
               //code to delete
                break;

Comment: create this function and pass it as 
`case 1: this.onDelete(messageIdToDelete)`

Answer (score 0):

**please any one will write a delete message gifted code like functional component above class component to functional component**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

please change the way to call function

onLongPress={this.onLongPress}
       to
 onLongPress={() => { this.onLongPress() }}

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help, but the code brokes when i change the code to this... any other idea?